# Android - Firebase Deeplink URL is lost when we call the deeplink URL from another website instead of passing it directly in href tag

Tags: firebase, temenos-quantum

We are using hybrid platform - kony for mobile application(android and IOS).

I have configured dynamic links in firebase dynamic links section. When we add the links directly in our email buttons as href tag and if user clicks that link in gmail from mobile browser it's working without any issues in both android and ios. Received dynamic link URL in mobile app and able to navigate user to particular screen based on URL params.

But for tracking purpose(Analytics), on click of that email button we are redirecting the user to our vendor website from there it is getting redirected to firebase dynamic URL. By doing in this way, IOS is working as expected, user is taken to particular screen.
But android has issues. App is opened in normal mode instead of deeplink mode. dynamic link is missing. So we couldn't navigate user to that particular screen.

I have added valid SHA-1 and SHA-256 release keys as well in my firebase project.
I have valid assetlinks.json file for the domain which i created. It's a custom domain with xxx.page.link(below one for reference).

**URL which is used in href tag**: http://t.XXX.com/click_stats/?ID=xxxx&ContactID=xxxxx&Tracking=98c68752ea4f4af1ab9922178ff608c1&StepId=128262

**Firebase Deeplink URL**: https://xxx.page.link/frmOffers

So 1st link will be added in email buttons href tags-  when user clicks 1st link,we will capture analytics and redirect to 1st link. Android app is opening but not in deeplink mode. Link url params are missing.

Please check and help. If IOS is working why android is not working.

```
[{"relation":["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],"target":{"namespace":"android_app","package_name":"com.xxx.xxx","sha256_cert_fingerprints":"xxxx"}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write an Kony FFI for this we handled this kind of use case recently and solved via FFI.